# What is the use of -y in CentOs 7 command

Tags: centos7

Command

`yum -y install httpd`

and in other commands while installing software or services online

Answer (score 1):

Type `man yum` to see the options.

```
-y, --assumeyes
Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
Configuration Option: assumeyes
```